# Why am I getting an Internal Server Error when trying to create a user, when it has worked fine until a few days ago with no changes to the code?

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods, internal-server-error

I am no longer able to add users to my site. There has been no changes to the code, I have not messed with it in any form. I get an error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'inviteUsers' { Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [CH2PR04CA0027.namprd04.prod.outlook.com]
I20200207-09:39:47.665(-5)?     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/Users/ygerardo/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.13zisy2.tjif++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:19)
I20200207-09:39:47.665(-5)?     at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/Users/ygerardo/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.13zisy2.tjif++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1254:34)
I20200207-09:39:47.666(-5)?     at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/Users/ygerardo/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.13zisy2.tjif++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1216:18)
I20200207-09:39:47.666(-5)?     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/Users/ygerardo/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.13zisy2.tjif++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:707:20)
I20200207-09:39:47.666(-5)?     at SMTPConnection._onData (/Users/ygerardo/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.13zisy2.tjif++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:510:14)
I20200207-09:39:47.666(-5)?     at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/Users/ygerardo/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.13zisy2.tjif++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:658:51)
I20200207-09:39:47.666(-5)?     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
I20200207-09:39:47.666(-5)?     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?   code: 'EAUTH',
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?   response: '535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [CH2PR04CA0027.namprd04.prod.outlook.com]',
I20200207-09:39:47.667(-5)?   responseCode: 535,
I20200207-09:39:47.668(-5)?   command: 'AUTH LOGIN' }
```

This is supposed to send an email to the new user to create a password. Now all of a sudden it is telling me that I don't have authentication. Here is the method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  inviteUsers: function(emailList){
  emailList.forEach((user)=>{
  const currentCompany =  Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()}).profile.company;
  if(user.email && user.first_name && user.last_name && user.role){
    Email.send({
       to: user.email,
       from: "donotreply@especsoftware.com",
       subject: "Welcome to SafeT1st",
       html: '<body>\
       <h3>Welcome to SafeT1st!</h3>\
       <p>You have been registered as a user in our system. You will recieve another email 
        from us with a password reset link. Please reset your password in order to access 
        the system.</p>\
       <p>Thanks for choosing SafeT1st!</p>\
       </body>'
    });

     let sponsorIsEmail = user.sponsor.includes("@");

     if(sponsorIsEmail){
       let findSponsor = Accounts.findUserByEmail(user.sponsor);
       console.log(findSponsor);
       user.sponsor = findSponsor._id;
     }

     let userAccount = Accounts.createUser({
       email: user.email,
       password: SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN
     });

     Meteor.users.update(userAccount,{
       $set: {
         "profile.first_name": user.first_name,
         "profile.last_name": user.last_name,
         "profile.company": currentCompany,
         "profile.locationId": user.locationId,
         "profile.permission": user.role,
         "profile.sponsor": user.sponsor
       }
     });

     Roles.addUsersToRoles(userAccount, user.role);
     Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail(userAccount);
   }else{
     throw new Meteor.Error("incorrect-csv-data", "One or more of the entries were incorrect or missing required fields. If uploading a .csv file check your file. Any correct entries were still added. Please check your manage users section for all details and users. If you need further .csv assistance please download the sample .csv file.");
  }

    });
  }
});
```

The code works fine up until the "Email.send({});" part.
I have tried restarting the site, re-uploading the code, deleting cache and cookies, searched for alternative to send emails.

Comment: Looks like the mail server does not authenticate anymore

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Strange thing, it was that the password for the email address was expired and had to be updated before it would allow access.